# Is it possible to run Elasticsearch and Magento on the same server?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, search

Is it possible to run Elasticsearch and Magento on the same server or do I definitely need a second one?

I know that will depend on the shop but maybe someone can give a estimation.

Comment: do whatever if your server has enough resources

Comment: Sure but what do I need to run Elasticsearch. This is helpful http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, as @PiTheNumber said you can check out the requirements [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html). Still I would recommend using a second server to host it.

Elastic Search can be rather resource heavy and you don't want to Elastic dragging down the performance of your webshop. An AWS or Digital Ocean server isn't too expensive and offers a great way to host an elastic database